# Azure AD B2C - same user with multiple client accounts

Tags: vue.js, asp.net-core, azure-ad-b2c, msal.js

I have multiple apps registered with azure AD including UI/API.
User attributes contains "customer id", "role" for permissions to the applications.
Each user has value for "customer Id" in user attribute, this is returned in access token for customer specific data. => a user for one customer.

**updated scenario**: "user a" is an admin for "customerA", also same "user a" needs to be manager role for "customer b". => a user for multiple customers.

how to handle this - provided customerid extracted from token ? On UI user should be able to switch from customer to another.

to try
I have created table in own database for this, and it will require me re-write all the api to not extract customer id from token, but depend on UI/API.

any alternative suggestion ?

Comment: So when the user logs in, they need to “select an account” and this should be reflected in the token?

Comment: That would be good, if its possible. Is it ?

Comment: @JasSuri is there way to configure wild card sub-domains for the application.
e.g. *.myapp.com for customerA.myapp.com, customerB.myapp.com. how does Azure devops do it ?

Comment: There is a [Sample](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/selectemail) which helps you to retrieve a String Collection from and API of emails associated with a user, it will then use javascript to allow the user to select the desired email. 
Based on the user selection you can call the Microsoft Graph API and get the required claims.

Comment: Regarding the Wild card sub domain Wildcard URIs like https://*.contoso.com may seem convenient, but should be avoided due to security implications.Please refer the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reply-url#restrictions-on-wildcards-in-redirect-uris)